# Is there a way to set a default parameter to the result of a user function in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'd like to specify a function return value for a `.ps1`'s default parameter.

Basically, I have a parameter `$Threads` which is a count of the maximum number of "threads" it is allowed to spawn at a time.  By default I want it to use the number of CPUs that are available.  This is what I have and it works:

```
Param(
    $Threads=((get-counter "\Processor(*)\% idle time").countersamples).length-1,
)
```

The problem with this is that it is ugly and when I get detailed help, it states the default value as:

```
-Threads <Object>
    States how many threads are to be used to check if there are tests in the 
    files.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    3
    Default value                ((get-counter "\Processor(*)\% idle 
    time").countersamples).length-1
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

I'd like that to be more intuitive by putting the default value into a function like so:

```
function number-of-cpus
{
    ((get-counter "\Processor(*)\% idle time").countersamples).length-1
}
```

which I would then add to my Param declaration, something like:

```
Param(
    $Threads=$(number-of-cpus),
)
```

which would then trickle down to show it in the detailed help as well.  Something like this:

```
-Threads <Object>
    States how many threads are to be used to check if there are tests in the 
    files.

    Required?                    false
    Position?                    3
    Default value                $(number-of-cpus)
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

However, I can't seem to do it in a way that works.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: All you want is a custom string in `Default value` field?

Comment: @PetSerAl, I'm not sure what you mean.  I want a custom value for a parameter.  That value should be a name which is more meaningful than say `((get-counter "\Processor(*)\% idle`.  I figured that a function name would fit the bill.

Comment: Thanks @PetSerAl.  That is what I was looking for.